# Node gets instantly killed - MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, crash

I've been trying to debug why is this happening and how can I fix it so that i can work!
The problem looks like this:

```
➜  ~ node
[1]    2912 killed     node
```

It happens with `yarn` and `npm` so i assumed its `node`. I cant find any `node` mention in `/var/log/system.log`.
I tried reinstalling node via brew but error persists. I reinstalled yarn as well.
What else can I do find out why this is hapening? Where is this being logged to?

BTW: I'm not running out of memory, i have available ram and hard disk space

I opened the "Console" utility app and found this error when i try to start nodejs:

`proc 4298: load code signature error 2 for file "node"`

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you open `Console.app` to see the crash reports and the reason for the node crash is `EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))`.

> This happens frequently if you use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n), every time you change versions, the new executable doesn't have the correct signature.

You need to  run:

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /usr/local/bin/node
```

Se more details here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40827

Comment: This answer helped me. It happens when you switch node version via "n" package

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same issue on new Macos Big Sur and I fixed this problem by following those steps, I hope it will save someone's time:

This is what I was getting

```
➜  ~ node
[1]    12187 killed     node
```

In the Console I found that error message pointed to icu4c

```
CODE SIGNING: process 11193[node]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x1047f4000 from offset 0x0 in file "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/67.1/lib/libicui18n.67.1.dylib" (cs_mtime:1614412395.998493416 == mtime:1614412395.998493416) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 nx:0 wpmapped:0 dirty:0 depth:0)
```

so I uninstalled the node and icu4c packages (if you have yarn, you may also want to uninstall it)

```
➜  ~ brew uninstall node
Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/15.10.0... (3,390 files, 54.9MB)
➜  ~ brew uninstall icu4c
Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/67.1... (258 files, 72.4MB)
```

then I ran one additional command, just to remove anything that's not needed.
`brew cleanup`

after that I ran `brew install node` and it started working!
Here's a log from my terminal:

```
➜  ~ brew install node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/icu4c-67.1.arm64_big_sur.bo
Already downloaded: /Users/pgoca/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0ead47d11680c7b6ed4d76eb2a934878314e34e9ac979b5306b6fb7a1ac3f8ae--icu4c-67.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-15.10.0.arm64_big_sur.
Already downloaded: /Users/pgoca/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5e38af944729bd333a4217bf8327099595ebec3a5e7c5eb1029399555828e39b--node-15.10.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Installing dependencies for node: icu4c
==> Installing node dependency: icu4c
==> Pouring icu4c-67.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include"

==> Summary
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/67.1: 258 files, 72.4MB
==> Installing node
==> Pouring node-15.10.0.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/15.10.0: 3,390 files, 54.9MB
==> Caveats
==> icu4c
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include"

➜  ~ node
Welcome to Node.js v15.10.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Comment: To investigate that specific case, we can directly filter for "CODE SIGNING" in Console, and `brew reinstall icu4c` if it's caused by icu4c, or `brew reinstall brotli` if it's caused by brotli.

Answer (score 3):

FIXED

I fixed by completely removing node and reinstalling via nvm

Comment: you got lucky! this didn't work for me - and took 15 mins to compile that node version from source.

Answer (score 2):

I am on the M1 Mac Mini. The solution for me was to reinstall Homebrew. Steps:

1. Run the official uninstall script: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`
2. Clean up: `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`
3. Fresh install: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
4. `brew install node`

Comment: I was going through this, but realized I use n or nvm to manage node versions. If you're doing the same the above will just nerf your brew packages without fixing anything.