# Can't run node or npm, getting the message "zsh: killed" or "Killed: 9" when running on bash

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, zsh

Not sure if related, but over the weekend I upgraded my OS to Big Sur version 11.1 and then when I began working one thing went wrong after another and now I can't use node or npm at all. I get the following message in zsh:

> % node -v
>
> zsh: killed     node -v

And the following on bash

> node -v
>
> Killed: 9

I've tried to install different versions of node through `n`, which makes no difference.

### How it got this way?

Prior to this issue (after my OS upgrade), I couldn't run `npm install`, and would get the following message:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

This seems to have been reported [on this thread, but as of writing this there are no replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286917/cant-install-npm-packages-anymore-due-to-macos-big-sur-upgrade).

As the OP on that thread says, I tried installing npm v7, which initially did solve my problem with the `npm install`, however caused other issues on the project.

I then decided to use `n` to install the latest version of `node` and this caused the errors I have above.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Edit: I was forced to uninstall and reinstall node to be able to go back to work, which did solve it but I am leaving this thread up in case there is a better solution.

Comment: Please check if your system is running out of memory. Do you have configured swap?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```
brew uninstall git
brew update
brew reinstall pcre2 gettext
brew install git
brew reinstall node
```

I'm sure there's a more surgical solution (e.g., maybe you don't need `brew reinstall pcre2 gettext`), but this ^^ worked for me. Below is the path I took:

Skimming some google results, seemed it was at least partly due to the new M1 silicon and the minor MacOS update to 11.2.2. Tried to `brew update` and got:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true` was terminated by uncaught signal KILL.
```

Which led me to this: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10275#issuecomment-757351887. After doing these uninstall, reinstall, installs, I finished with a `brew reinstall node` and voilà! Didn't need to uninstall node and install from scratch:

```
an@As-Air ~ % node -v
v15.11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

The solution is to reinstall node *and all its dependencies*. Luckily, Homebrew offers a one-liner all-in-one solution:

```
brew reinstall $(brew deps node) node
```

### Why?

I had followed @albielin and @Mariusz' solutions without success. I didn't yet want the @bgh's nuclear option to reinstall Homebrew with all its packages.

It seems in my case, the issue wasn't coming from those specific dependencies (`pcre2 gettext openssl icu4c`), but rather another one. No need to worry about `git`. But do reinstall all dependencies to be sure and avoid an endless trial-and-error with every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Tried @albielin approach but it still didn't work for me. Ive took a look in the console and saw issues with openssl and icu4c when executing `node --version` and reinstalled both. Now it works.

So in addition to @albielin commands I did:

```
brew reinstall openssl
brew reinstall icu4c
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The answers above didn't work for me. Looking at the console while running `node --version` I found the error `load code signature error 2 for file "node"`

Reinstalling Homebrew as detailed in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258998/359765) did it for me:

1. Run the official uninstall script: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`
2. Clean up: `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`
3. Fresh install: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
4. Install node: `brew install node`

The node post-install process ran into a few issues due to symlinks that could not be overwritten. The advice given in [this article](https://intertherabbithole.wordpress.com/2018/04/01/homebrew-npm-install-could-not-symlink/) helped me resolve this; a few `sudo chown ...` and `brew link --overwrite node` commands later node was successfully installed!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while running command `npm run dev`.
But when I tried with command `npm start`, then it started working and I was able to open documentation.