# Mac M1 why node js is not running in OS terminal but in IDE terminals?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, zsh, apple-m1

On a M1 MacBook Air i installed node 14.x and 16.x by NVM (NVM was installed by homebrew)

If I run `node -v` on iTerm or OS terminal I always get `zsh: killed     node -v`

But if I run the same command within the integrated terminal of either VSCode, Rubymine or Marta, node runs fine yielding version number. (And I can develop using node, too)

Can someone explain why this is happening. What are the differences between the different terminals? Don't the all use same zsh in the background?

Comment: Some answers suggest reinstalling Homebrew and node. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993253/node-gets-instantly-killed-macos), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66119081/996081)

Answer (score 1):

The below command will help in identifying which kernel you are using.

```
ps -p $$
```

Try executing the above command and compare the kernels.

If in case you wish to change your system's default kernel, you can follow below steps: -

> Change the default shell to Bash by running the following command:
>
> ```
> chsh -s /bin/bash
> ```
>
> You’ll have to enter your user account’s password. Finally, close the Terminal window and reopen it. You’ll be using Bash instead of Zsh.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, and if you have used brew to install node and it can be related to brew installation as mentioned in the below post:

[node-gets-instantly-killed-macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993253/node-gets-instantly-killed-macos)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think that's not the case here:

vscode:
xxxx@MacBookAir ~ % ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 2174 ttys001    0:00.14 /bin/zsh -l

seems all mentioned integrated terminals use zsh.

Comment: This problem seems to be generic to MacOS . Please try this once :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993253/node-gets-instantly-killed-macos

Answer (score 0):

Since I had a bunch of other problems with killed processes that where installed by homebrew (and then only run after reinstalling) I decided to completely uninstall and reinstall homebrew. Not sure if it helps, but others noted this as some solution to the problem.

another helpful post:
[Why does zsh kills my process every time I enter a git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119081/why-does-zsh-kills-my-process-every-time-i-enter-a-git-command)

same issue, similar solution.